# Can one make move_iterator from istream_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, istream-iterator, iterator-traits

Consider following code:

```
typedef istream_iterator<char> char_itr ;
char_itr eos;

string ll("some text here");

istringstream line_in(ll);
char_itr start(line_in);

move_iterator<char_itr> mstart(start); // !!!
move_iterator<char_itr> meos(eos);
vector<char> vc(mstart, meos);
```

Above code will not compile because of line (!!!):

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const char' to 'char &&'
```

But if you replace `mstart` and `meos` with `start` and `eos`, respectively (regular iterators), the code will compile. Why I can't make `move_iterators`?

**EDIT:**
For those wondering why I would like to move a character from a stream/string. Actual problem involves more complex data type than `char` which copying from a string should be avoided. `char` was used just for the sake of simplicity, to present the mechanism causing error.

Comment: Think about what you're trying to do for a while, do you really think you can *move* characters *from* a stream? It seems to me that you're trying to do some premature optimization.

Comment: There is no difference between moving and copying a `char` anyway. It's just a byte!

Comment: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2106

Comment: @ecatmur The issue title is misleading. The definition of `move_iterator::reference` is changed even for this case.

Comment: @ecatmur You are still missing the point. Pre-LWG2106, `move_iterator<I>::reference` is `I::value_type &&` aka `T&&`. Post-LWG2106, `move_iterator<I>::reference`, for `I::reference` being a real reference, is `std::remove_reference_t<I::reference>&&` aka `T const&&`. (`iterator_traits` dance omitted for simplicity.)

Comment: @T.C. ah, I understand now. So, post LWG2106 it'll compile but it'll do the wrong thing in this case, since the `move_iterator` will return `T const&&`. Possibly not an improvement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There was a discussion of this on the std-discussion newsgroup earlier this year: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/h7jGY95j1oc

The consensus appears to be that `istream_iterator::reference` is `T const&` to enforce the `InputIterator` contract; that is, to prevent users writing `*it = value;`. Unfortunately, this also prevents moving from the cached value.

As T.C. mentioned above, post the resolution to [LWG2106](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2106) the code will compile; unfortunately because `move_iterator::reference` will be `T const&&` it will silently do the wrong thing, most likely invoking the copy constructor of your type.

Since `istream_iterator` modifies the cached value when incremented, it is (from a language POV) legal to `const_cast` the returned reference to `T&`. Unfortunately (again) that doesn't help here as there's no easy way to interpose a `const_cast` between the `istream_iterator` and `move_iterator`.

Possible workaround solutions:

- write your own `istream_iterator`, with a non-const `reference` typedef;
- write your own `move_iterator` performing `const_cast`;
- write an interposing `const_cast` iterator;
- use a mutable wrapper around the value type.

The latter option is surprisingly easy:

```
template<class T>
  struct mutable_wrapper {
    T mutable value;
    operator T&() const { return value; }
  };
// ...
using itr = std::istream_iterator<mutable_wrapper<MyType>>;
```

[Example](http://goo.gl/EDtySd).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `istream_iterator::reference`, we see that it's `T const &`. Dereferencing the iterator gives us such a reference. But to be able to move from something, that something needs to be modifiable. That's what the error message is trying to tell you.

You could make a `move_iterator` from an `istream_iterator`, by putting some custom iterator that keeps an internal (non const) storage inbetween.

But why would you want to move from an `istream_iterator`? Those are *single pass iterators*, and thus likely have nearly no internal storage.